# Mongoose/MongoDB won't connect from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i'm new to MongoDB/Mongoose, I am following many different tutorials online about how to connect my node.js server to mongodb using mongoose, however none of them seem to mention the issue i'm having.  I have mongo server running on my machine, I can manipulate it find from the command line, but when connecting from node i run into a few problems.  Mainly, its that It still says waiting for connections on Port 27017 but the connection is never made, the db I define in mongoose is never created, but also, I don't get any errors.

I do get some deprecation warnings regarding both body-parser and URL string parser.  Not sure what to do about that.  But also, i'm trying to log either a connection confirmation or an error if it can't connect. Instead it just logs a monster mongoose(?) object.  See below

```
body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares server.js:15:9                            body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules\body-parser\index.js:105:29             (node:12152) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.                                         connected to [object Promise]  +  NativeConnection {                                                                      base:                                                                                                                    Mongoose {                                                                                                                connections: [ [Circular] ],                                                                                            models: { users: [Function] },                                                                                          modelSchemas: { users: [Schema] },                                                                                      options: { pluralization: true },                                                                                       _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],                                                                                      Schema:                                                                                                                  { [Function: Schema] reserved: [Object], Types: [Object], ObjectId: [Function] },                                      model: [Function],                                                                                                      plugins: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ] },                                                                   collections:                                                                                                             { users:                                                                                                                   NativeCollection {                                                                                                        collection: [Collection],                                                                                               opts: [Object],                                                                                                         name: 'users',                                                                                                          collectionName: 'users',                                                                                                conn: [Circular],                                                                                                       queue: [],                                                                                                              buffer: false,                                                                                                          emitter: [EventEmitter] } },                                                                                      models:                                                                                                                  { users:                                                                                                                   { [Function: model]                                                                                                       hooks: [Kareem],                                                                                                        base: [Mongoose],                                                                                                       modelName: 'users',                                                                                                     model: [Function: model],                                                                                               db: [Circular],                                                                                                         discriminators: undefined,                                                                                              events: [EventEmitter],                                                                                                 '$appliedMethods': true,                                                                                                '$appliedHooks': true,                                                                                                  _middleware: [Kareem],                                                                                                  schema: [Schema],                                                                                                       collection: [NativeCollection],                                                                                         Query: [Function],                                                                                                      '$__insertMany': [Function],                                                                                            '$init': [Promise],                                                                                                     '$caught': true,                                                                                                        [Symbol(mongoose#Model)]: true } },                                                                               config: { autoIndex: true },                                                                                            replica: false,                                                                                                         options: null,                                                                                                          otherDbs: [],                                                                                                           relatedDbs: {},                                                                                                         states:                                                                                                                  [Object: null prototype] {                                                                                                '0': 'disconnected',                                                                                                    '1': 'connected',                                                                                                       '2': 'connecting',                                                                                                      '3': 'disconnecting',                                                                                                   '99': 'uninitialized',                                                                                                  disconnected: 0,                                                                                                        connected: 1,                                                                                                           connecting: 2,                                                                                                          disconnecting: 3,                                                                                                       uninitialized: 99 },                                                                                                 _readyState: 1,                                                                                                         _closeCalled: false,                                                                                                    _hasOpened: true,                                                                                                       '$internalEmitter':                                                                                                      EventEmitter {                                                                                                            _events: [Object: null prototype] { dropDatabase: [Function] },                                                         _eventsCount: 1,                                                                                                        _maxListeners: 0 },                                                                                                  _listening: false,                                                                                                      _connectionOptions:                                                                                                      { promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise], useNewUrlParser: false },                                                       name: 'financeDB',                                                                                                      host: 'localhost',                                                                                                      port: 27017,                                                                                                            user: undefined,                                                                                                        pass: undefined,                                                                                                        client:                                                                                                                  MongoClient {                                                                                                             _events: [Object: null prototype] { left: [Function] },                                                                 _eventsCount: 1,                                                                                                        _maxListeners: undefined,                                                                                               s:                                                                                                                       { url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/financeDB',                                                                             options: [Object],                                                                                                      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],                                                                                    dbCache: [Object],                                                                                                      sessions: [] },                                                                                                      topology:                                                                                                                Server {                                                                                                                  _events: [Object],                                                                                                      _eventsCount: 26,                                                                                                       _maxListeners: Infinity,                                                                                                clientInfo: [Object],                                                                                                   s: [Object] } },                                                                                                  '$initialConnection': Promise { <pending> },                                                                            db:                                                                                                                      Db {                                                                                                                      _events:                                                                                                                 [Object: null prototype] { reconnect: [Function], close: [Function], timeout: [Function] },                            _eventsCount: 3,                                                                                                        _maxListeners: undefined,                                                                                               s:                                                                                                                       { databaseName: 'financeDB',                                                                                              dbCache: {},                                                                                                            children: [],                                                                                                           topology: [Server],                                                                                                     options: [Object],                                                                                                      logger: [Logger],                                                                                                       bson: BSON {},                                                                                                          readPreference: [ReadPreference],                                                                                       bufferMaxEntries: -1,                                                                                                   parentDb: null,                                                                                                         pkFactory: undefined,                                                                                                   nativeParser: undefined,                                                                                                promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],                                                                                    noListener: false,                                                                                                      readConcern: undefined },                                                                                            serverConfig: [Getter],                                                                                                 bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],                                                                                             databaseName: [Getter] } }
```

So why is this printing and what am I doing wrong re connection?  Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');
    config = require('.DB');

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(config.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true}).then(
        ()=> {console.log('Database is connected')},
        err=>{console.log('Can not connect to the database' + err)}
    );

    const app = express();
    let port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    const server = app.listen(function(){
        console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
    });
```

and my DB.js is just the uri

```
module.exports = {
    DB: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ng7crud'
};
```

Comment: Have you checked if config.DB is actually fetching the uri from DB.js or not?

Comment: I hard coded the uri in to server.js to check and it still didn't make a difference